# Firebase database rules No such method/property 'child'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm new to firebase rules and am trying to write rules for the chat part of my web app. The chat part of my database has chatroom children which have 3 children each: user1, user2, and msgs. user1 has a value of one of the member's uid's, user2 has the value of the other member's uid, and msgs is an object made up of the message strings.

When a user starts a chat with another user, I want to make sure that the chatroom created follows the following criteria:

1) Either user1 or user2 value equals the user's uid.

2) Either user1 or user2 value equals the other member's uid.

3) The other member's uid is in the user's friends list.

Here is what I wrote in bolt:

```
path /chats/{chat} is Chat{
    read() {isInChat(auth, chat)}               // Can only read if user's uid is equal to user1 or user2's value
    write() {createOnly(this)}                  // Can only append the chatroom to list of chatrooms
    validate() {(chat.child('user1').val() == auth.uid || chat.child('user2').val() == auth.uid) && isFriend(auth, chat) }
}

function isInChat (auth, chatRoom) {            // Check if user1 or user2 is equal to user's uid
    return chatRoom.child('user1').val() == auth.uid || chatRoom.child('user2').val() == auth.uid;
}
function isFriend (auth, chat) {                // Check if other member of chat is in the user's friends list
    return root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('friends').child(chat.child('user1').val()) != null || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('friends').child(chat.child('user2').val()) != null;
}
function createOnly (value) {                   // Make sure node being created does not already exist
    return prior(value) == null && value != null;
}
type Chat {
  user1: String,
  user2: String,
  msgs: Object
}
```

This generates the following rules:

```
 "chats": {
      "$chat": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user1', 'user2', 'msgs']) 
                   && ($chat.child('user1').val() == auth.uid 
                    || $chat.child('user2').val() == auth.uid) 
                   && (newData.parent().parent().child('users').child(auth.uid).child('friends').child($chat.child('user1').val()) != null 
                    || newData.parent().parent().child('users').child(auth.uid).child('friends').child($chat.child('user2').val()) != null)",
        "user1": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "user2": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "msgs": {
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": "false"
        },
        ".read": "$chat.child('user1').val() == auth.uid
               || $chat.child('user2').val() == auth.uid",
        ".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() != null"
      }
    }
  }
```

However, when I try publish the rules I get the error `No such method/property 'child'` for the first `.validate` line and the `.read` line.

Can anyone please help me understand what is wrong with my rules and whether I'm approaching this correctly?

Comment: Can you show the write operation that gets rejected?

Comment: Hey frank, the write operation doesn't get rejected, I worded it wrong. The actual rule save gets rejected

Comment: Frank, for example the `.read` rule gets the error  `No such method/property 'child'`: `"chats": {
      "$chat": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user1', 'user2', 'msgs'])",
        "user1": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "user2": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "msgs": {
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren()"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": "false"
        },
        ".read": "$chat.child('user1').val() == auth.uid || $chat.child('user2').val() == auth.uid"
      }`

Comment: Ah, I see it now. `$chat.child('user1')` is indeed not valid. When you use `$chat` is essentially evaluates to the string value of the key and a string variable doesn't have a a `child` method. What are you trying to access there? If you're looking to get the `user1` value of the new data, you should use `newData.child('user1').val()`. If you're want to access the existing data, it's `data.child('user1').val()`.

Comment: Sweet, thanks Frank! I'm making good progress writing my rules for my chrome extension, all thanks to you! I'll probably have more questions though :)

Comment: Sounds good Mark. Just make sure to include the **minimum** code that reproduces the problem. That allows us to spot the problem faster and thus help more people.